# integrating a database with easy manual maintenence

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, spreadsheet

I have some information I want to try to integrate into a project I'm working on. It would be "publically maintained" by volunteers in the community I would be working with.

The idea I had was to keep things simple for the people doing the maintenence: I would give them access to a shared google docs spreadsheet and let them do their thing when stuff needed to be updated. I would update the database using this spreadsheet on some automated daily or weekly interval.

I've never worked with databases before. My project is in C++ and my searching around for a database to use seemed to point to sqlite. The data wouldn't be anything complex, just a unique id with a name. maybe an additional piece of information but unlikely.

I'm mostly concerned about getting the data to be an actual database. I looked around for some conversion tool(I assumed spreadsheet -> database would be trivial?). I'm up for any ideas on how to make this work. Thanks

Comment: Why not just have a web-interface for the database itself? That would avoid having to do a second stage update.

Comment: I thought about this

1. I don't have a website

2. I'm unsure of the ease of editing a web database. If it's as "simple" as loading up a spreadsheet and editing information in a spreadsheet then I could see it possible.

Comment: Well, if you are the one making the website, then I guess you can make it as easy or as hard as you like. It really depends on what you are actually trying to achieve too. I volunteer as a programmer for two medium sized websites (several thousand distinct pages, but a large quantity of that is "machine generated", but there are still several dozen different layouts and types of pages).

Comment: Is there going to be so much data that you actually need a proper database, or would say loading a csv file into memory be good enough?

Comment: Mats: issue is I don't really know much about database software enough to know how implementation works and if it will be user friendly to contribute information. basically I have no idea what kind of gui interfaces exist for database editing and if they exist that they are easily implementable in webform. absolutely clueless in all areas :)

@Adam i'd never heard of that format. it seems easy enough for me to work with(output spreadsheet to csv, import to sqlite). The data will be maybe 50-100 identifiers and a name. trivial stuff. if you forsee any complications let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using google docs with output as tsv/csv and sticking that in sqlite will work fine for me, thanks.